# Term for a person responsible for the next action

Tags: word-choice

I am designing a system that tracks a complicated workflow. Each step of the workflow has a different person assigned to take an action. What is a succinct term I could use to describe the person who is responsible for the currently active step?

I considered "owner", but that more accurately describes the person who initiated the instance of the workflow. The ball is in this person's court. Who is he?

Comment: Around here we call it the "stuckee".

Comment: The answers to this question may be useful...http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117734/what-is-the-player-called-who-has-a-turn

Comment: That link was helpful. A few of the terms, such as "at bat", describe the situation well for me. However, since this is not a game, I don't feel that a gaming term is appropriate. Absent of a better answer, I may go with "initiative".

Comment: In our in-house IT ticketing system, we use "*assignee*".

Answer (score 2):

I would generally describe any facet of a workflow that performs an action an 'actor', be it a person, or some automated part of the process.

ac·tor
ˈaktər
noun

a participant in an action or process.
"employers are key actors within industrial relations"

You might say 'current actor' or something similar if you are trying to convey the fact that this is the actor who's input is pending.

Comment: @idor_brad, notice that you wrote, "...the person who is responsible for the currently *active* step." (emphasis added.) In your program, if you plan to describe the current step as the "active" step, then Dave Magner is doubly correct: *actor* is the parallel word to describe the person most closely related to the *active* step. If you plan to use a different word for the current step, then it is possible you will want a different word for the person.

Comment: I'm probably overanalyzing this, but if a process is waiting on a person to participate, but they are not necessarily participating, are they still a "participant"? In other words, if a document is in my inbox awaiting my signature, am I the "actor" in the process although I haven't opened my mail yet?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [***executor***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/executor)

> 2.0 A person who produces something or puts something into effect:

This follows after the dominant usage: the person assigned to execute the final will of a person who has died.

If the connotation of death makes executor objectionable, then [*agent* (2)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/agent), [*operative*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/operative?searchDictCode=all), [*operator* (2)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/operator) or [*assignee* (2)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/assignee) might work.

Comment: _1 for *agent*.